# Change javascript output locale

Tags: javascript

Im in trouble with this javascript. Im not good with this language, so i thought, maby you can help me with it. This script changes value of the input which id end_date. But when it chages it prints in eng locale, i need to change it to lt. Like this: `setlocale(LC_ALL, '$AppUI->user_lang.UTF-8');` Help pls.

```
f.task_end_date.value = e.getUTCFullYear()+tz2+(e.getMonth()+1)+tz1+e.getDate();
var url = '?m=public&a=date_format&dialog=1&field='+f.name+'.end_date&date=' + f.task_end_date.value;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Moment.js to parse/format the date to the format that you need: http://momentjs.com/